# Update a column for all the rows

Tags: sql

Table name: `Employee`
Column Name: `Emp_name`

`Emp_name` has this contents:

```
xx\rama,
xx\rajesh,
xx\vignesh
```

I have to update the table Employee by removing `xx\` from all the rows of column `Emp_name`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
UPDATE Employee
SET EMP_Name = REPLACE(Emp_name, 'xx\', '')
```

This will remove all occurences of `xx\` in all records.

Comment: Thanks for your response. can you please let me know how to Update only the first row in above column of table Employee?

Comment: You can't since you are erasing what makes those rows identifiable.

Answer (score 5):

```
update Employee set
Emp_name = substring(Emp_name, 4)
where Emp_name like 'xx\\%'; -- escaped backslash as per your database flavour
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. I think the last line needs to be changed to `where Emp_name like 'xx\\%'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. can you please let me know how to Update only the first row in above column of table Employee?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [Employee]
SET Emp_Name=REPLACE(Emp_Name, 'xx\', '')
```

---

If you just want to just update the first, then do:

```
UPDATE [Employee]
SET Emp_Name=REPLACE(Emp_Name, 'xx\', '')
WHERE Emp_Id=(SELECT MIN(Emp_Id) FROM [Employee])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. can you please let me know how to Update only the first row in column of table Employee table?

Comment: This depends on what you describe as the first row. What columns are in your table? Do you have a Primary Key field? What is the value of the Primary Key field which you class as the first row?

Comment: I have taken Emp_id as my Primary key

Comment: One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "2" constrains table "GEOUW.USERS" from having duplicate values for the index key.. SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, DRIVER=4.12.79

I got this error when I ran the First update statement you you provided.

Comment: it worked for me. So can i know how to roll back the above update statement. ex: emp name is RAMA now. I have to get XX/RAMA now. I have to update it in all rows.

Answer (score -1):

I"m assuming this is in MS SQL, so if it is, this should work

update Employee

set emp_name = right(emp_name, len(emp_name) - 3)

Comment: Thanks for your response. can you please let me know how to Update only the first row in above column of table Employee?

Comment: well, if you know the emp_name you can update employee set emp_name right(emp_name, len(emp_name) - 3) where emp_name = 'somename' otherwise you can update employee set emp_name right(emp_name, len(emp_name) - 3) where emp_name = (select top 1 from employee)